# xcode app icon is not applied anymore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have been testing and developing my app since few months and now, app icon applied on device not correspond as icon set on target summary. I tried to remove it and attach it again but no succes! App icon appears on device as a small capture of splash screen! Why? How to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file name under the "Icon Files" key in the info.plist is same as your app icon file. You can view the info.plist by selecting the target and then selecting the "Info" tab.